# Where is my horse after I died?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I just got to chapter 4 where

> the gang moves to the swamp

and I bought the gold horse from the stable for $950. I only bought the horse because it was a war/racing horse breed. I did a couple of missions

> in Saint Denis

and then I returned to camp to do a Strauss mission when you go and collect debts from people who owe the gang. On the way to a "Catfish Jackson" house I was met with 10+ bandits that in the end they ended up killing me. After I died it put me back in the game but it gave me a Tennessee Walker horse as my main horse. I have died by bandits before and I have always responded back with the horse that I died with and this just confused me. I wasn't too mad because I still have about $7000 but I am just curious of what happened. If you have any idea please respond.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess your horse is either lost or dead.

Visit a Stable, or if you have the Horse Stable camp upgrade, and see if you can recall your horse. If not, it likely perished in the conflict.

Also, your current horse will be marked on the map. It will have a white saddle icon if it has died.